# The directory 'D:\dj\staticfiles' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist

Tags: django, django-templates

[This is my settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wocEI.png)

I already created a folder 'staticfiles' in the project folder. How can I solve the error

Comment: Can you please add the content of the image as text

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `STATIC_ROOT`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: I updated the STATIC_ROOT, then i was getting another error
"?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting."

Comment: rename your folder to static instead of staticfiles

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and it took about 5 hours but after putting these lines of codes in settings.py it worked fine.

**Just copy and paste these lines of code into settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```